WSL: Bash not showing package suggestions when a command is not found
I recently noticed my bash console on WSL stopped showing package suggetions suddenly. I often use zsh and decided to install commnad-not-found plugin with oh my zsh and it worked correctly.
.zshrc plugins:
# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting fast-syntax-highlighting command-not-found)

I tried installing command-not-found package, but didn't work:
$ sudo apt install command-not-found

Behavior:
$ sido
bash: sido: command not found

Expected result
$ sido
No command 'sido' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)

I can't really find an answer about how to solve this.

Bash and zsh are two (very) different shells (and much more mutually incompatible than most beginners realize). Be sure you're clear about which one you're using -- it's completely normal that configuring an interactive feature for zsh won't enable it for bash, and the inverse.

I might not being clear, i'm saying that in both shells, bash and zsh, suggestion won't show up anymore. I use both, and both share the problem. bash showed suggestions by default and then stopped suddenly.

Gotcha. Unfortunately, this is more a problem with files packaged and distributed by your distro than a question about bash as a programming language. If you can boil it down to a question about the language that can be answered without looking up the files packaged by your distro, that would make it on topic here.

did you start a new bash shell after installing the package? for it to work, the function command_not_found_handle must be defined (on Ubuntu this is done in /etc/bash.bashrc which is sourced by /etc/profile).
